# how do i model filigree details on a cylinder?

Tags: modeling

Hi guys I'm currently working on a spear model for practice learning blender. I've run into a bit of a tough spot and having a hard time figuring out the correct technique for modeling these filigree details that I've outlined in red.

[image]

I have tried using the poly build tool, making a plane that matches the design and shrinkwrapping it then adding depth, creating a whole new object and joining it, etc. In every method I can't see to either have it act nicely or conform to the shape of the cylinder. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "act nicely"? What's wrong with your current workflow?

Comment: with the shrinkwrap method, adding the solidify modifier results in weird artifacts and it gets scaled to a crazy value even though I only slightly change the value. when i try using a completely new object, say a cube modeled into the shape of those details, i cannot get it to lay nicely against the cylinder either by hand, using the bend tool, or shrinkwrap. there is always some type of weird geometry happening

Comment: Have you tried using selective extrusion of faces? The cylinder looks to have enough resolution to work with. By cutting along the details and then selectively extruding the parts you want to have depth.

Comment: i will try this out definitely tonight, thanks for the suggestion. i didn't think of cutting along the details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By cutting the cylinder and selective extrusion of the needed faces you can get there.

The cylinder you have in the picture seems to be good enough in resolution.

I made a visual explanation to show the steps.

Essentially, cutting to define the detail areas, dissolving edges to prepare for further cuts and extrusion along normals. Later adding further cuts to achieve the harder edge look. In the video/gif i left out one more cut at the lowest part to sharpen it there as well.

That said, here the show:

[image]

The closer you go along the details the better it will look, so excuse my fast run through. Also, i would usually try to avoid triangles, but since this is no character for animation and it was only for explanation, i hope you can overlook that ;)

Comment: wow this is great, thank you so much for putting all that together! i really appreciate it a ton!

Comment: Glad it helped, consider up-voting or if it's actually what you were looking for, accept it as answered please.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a normal map. You might check out [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ywSq0bSYLWI&list=PLjEaoINr3zgHJVJF3T3CFUAZ6z11jKg6a&t=0s) great video by blenderguru. It's a bit old, but the technique is the same.

Comment: Please don't use link only answers. If the link ever goes down, the information is gone for future users of the site. It is always better to include the relevant information as text in your answer.